# Display a "int **array" in C using ncurses

Tags: c, arrays, int, ncurses

How could I display an `int **array` instead of the spaces used in my defines in my.h? I'm using ncurses for the interface, and to display it instead of putting the strings in the .c file, I created a .h and defined all strings for the interface. Could some explain me how to do that?

Basically, in my .C file, I'll just do "mvprintw(..., MAP_1)"
But from MAP_2 to MAP_21, I'd like to replace spaces by an int **array

Here is my.h:

```
#ifndef MY_H_
# define MY_H_

# define HEADER_1 "      ______________________  _________\n"
# define HEADER_2 "     /_  __/ ____/_  __/ __ \\/  _/ ___/\n"
# define HEADER_3 "      / / / __/   / / / /_/ // / \\__ \\ \n"
# define HEADER_4 "     / / / /___  / / / _, _// / ___/ / \n"
# define HEADER_5 "    /_/ /_____/ /_/ /_/ |_/___//____/  \n"

# define MAP_1 "௦----------௦\n"
# define MAP_2 "|          |\n"
# define MAP_3 "|          |\n"
# define MAP_4 "|          |\n"
# define MAP_5 "|          |\n"
# define MAP_6 "|          |\n"
# define MAP_7 "|          |\n"
# define MAP_8 "|          |\n"
# define MAP_9 "|          |\n"
# define MAP_10 "|          |\n"
# define MAP_11 "|          |\n"
# define MAP_12 "|          |\n"
# define MAP_13 "|          |\n"
# define MAP_14 "|          |\n"
# define MAP_15 "|          |\n"
# define MAP_16 "|          |\n"
# define MAP_17 "|          |\n"
# define MAP_18 "|          |\n"
# define MAP_19 "|          |\n"
# define MAP_20 "|          |\n"
# define MAP_21 "|          |\n"
# define MAP_22 "௦----------௦\n"

#endif /* !MY_H_ */
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why `int **`? Perhaps you meant `char **`

Comment: @pmg Because I use an int ** for my tetris

Comment: @iNukeLaPeste: please explain why you are using `int **array;` by editing your question. It smells like a design mistake.

Comment: BTW, your header file is useless. It should contain the *commented* declaration of `array`  which is missing there. There is no reason to `#define` a lot of string literals there. You'll probably need these literals only once!

Comment: ncurses has both a `box()` and a `border()` function, so none of this is really necessary. Attribute and color information obviously won't fit into a plain `char`, so presumably that is the reason for the `int **`, although `chtype` rather than `int` would be the correct type for ncurses.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths Exactly why I'm using an int **. Okay so let's say I use a chtype array, how box() and border() is going to help me here? Cause if I do box() and border() it does it around the full window, I want my map to be in the middle of the screen for example.

Comment: @iNukeLaPeste: You can make a new window or a sub window for the map, and use either `box()` or `wborder()` with that. If you have a self-contained rectangular area that you want to work with, it makes sense to create a separate window for it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You display *strings* with `ncurses`. A string is an array of `char` (or perhaps a heap-allocated zone in a pointer) which is zero-byte terminated.

So copy (using `strcpy`  or `strncpy`) some string like `MAP_13` into some string buffer (perhaps a `char linebuf [128];`), and fill that buffer appropriately. Have some routine transforming a tetris line (some `array[i]`) into a string.

I would recommend (for ease of debugging, and to be sure of zero-byte termination) to clear that buffer (e.g. with `memset(linebuf, 0, sizeof(linebuf));` ....) before the copy.

BTW, for a tetris game, I won't use a matrix of `int`-s, but a matrix of `unsigned char`, or of some `enum`, or directly of *displayable* `char`-s

Comment: Thanks, but why should I use a char ** instead of an int **? Because an int ** would be easier for me. The array will contain spaces and * (which will be my tetris pieces - 4 * for a square, etc) and I have to color those * depending on which piece it is.

Comment: What makes you think that using `int` would be easier? What is the meaning of your `array`? (you should edit the question to improve it)

Answer (score 0):

You can define an array of char array like this:

```
// each of the N elements of array can hold strings up to 19 characters
char array[][20] = {
    "one",
    "two",
    "...",
    "forty two"
};
```

Answer (score 0):

There is more than one aspect to consider:

An **`int*`** array would be useful if OP wanted to print a given number of spaces on each line, e.g.,

```
int myarray[] = { 8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8 };

for (n = 1; n <= 22; ++n)
     printw("%*s\n", myarray[n], " ");
```

An **`int**`** array would be similar (but not giving the data declaration...) for example

```
for (n = 1; n <= 22; ++n)
     printw("%*s\n", *myindirect[n], " ");
```

and could be useful as well.